Data Grid - Editing - MUI add from API
I'm using Data Grid - Editing of mui to add a new row
When I click su Add Row I set a new row with empy field:
setRows((oldRows) => [...oldRows, { id: 0, aliquota: 0, descrizione: '', tipo: '', isFixed: false, isNew: true }]);

then I use processRowUpdate to send the api and return the new line
   const processRowUpdate = React.useCallback(
        async (newRow: GridRowModel) =>{
            let updatedRows = rows;
            if (newRow.tipo !== 'I') {
                newRow = { ...newRow, aliquota: 0 };
            }
            let aliquotaObj: AliquoteIva = {
                id: newRow.id,
                aliquota: newRow.aliquota,
                descrizione: newRow.descrizione,
                tipo: newRow.tipo,
                isFixed: newRow.isFixed
            };
            if(newRow.isNew){
                const res = await mutateRow(aliquotaObj);
                showAlert({ isOpen: true, severity: res.error ? 'error' : 'success',message: res.message,onClose: () => { }});
                if (!res.error && res.data?.id) {
                
                    return { ...newRow, id: res.data.id, isNew: false };
                }

            }else{
                const res = await mutateRowUpdate(aliquotaObj);
                showAlert({isOpen: true, severity: res.error ? 'error' : 'success',message: res.message,onClose: () => { }});
                if (!res.error) {
                    return { ...newRow, isNew: false };
                }
            }
           
        },
        [mutateRowUpdate]
    )

But the system add a new line instade of update the line with id:0
How can i handle this?
